# We need to increase your visits per day

Tags: discussion, advertising

Being that SE only seems to care about money and therefore views, this is more important that usual. Also, visits per day drives nearly everything else. More visits is more questions per day. More questions per day is more users with reputation. Percent answered and answer ratio are unrelated but were great on those. Our 2 worst metrics are visits per day and questions per day both of which have the same solution. Please, advertise this site on your **websites** (its going to be advertised on mine when I get approval from my co-founder), on your **programming languages** (I can't do this since I don't have one yet), on your **other communities, both in and out of Stack Exchange**, or in any other way you can think of. Remember that the home page for PLDI has sharing links to social media sites. There are many avid users not here and I'm sure many of them have questions on a regular basis and are more than happy to share their knowledge.

Comment: This is getting downvoted because the numbers don't support the framing of the situation. We went from very few visits per day (around 50) to a lot of visits per day (over 500). Assuming that the number is an average of some sort, that means that activity has *really* picked up since we entered public beta. The same can be said for questions. We were hovering around 3 questions per day, but now, we're over 5 questions per day. That's a big difference when you consider that these stats are averages across 40+ days.

Answer (score 5):

> Sites remain in beta for at least 180 days to build up a critical mass of users, questions, and participation. ([Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation))

We've been in public beta for 7 days and we're already at about 700 visits per day, up from about 50–100 per day in private beta. We have another 173 days before it matters whether we're at 1500 per day, and there is no indication that we aren't on course to reach or exceed that.

If anything, I would be more concerned about growing too quickly. It is difficult to ensure that new users will understand the community's standards and norms if too many new users arrive too quickly, because most of the other people they interact with will be other new users.

Comment: But our visits per day has been decreasing

Comment: @Starship-OnStrike ...it was slightly lower on the weekend, yes, like every Stack Exchange site's activity is every weekend.

Comment: As a side-note, the front page of Langdev Meta currently looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPzwY.png ─ maybe it would be a good idea to take a break for a bit.